# PB Functional test symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I try to do a functional test on a controller that executes doctrine. When I execute my test, it fails. but when I commented in my controller this line:"**$products = $em->getRepository("Couture\FrontBundle\Entity\Produit")->findAll()**".
my test is success.

**this is my controller:**

```
class ProductController extends Controller {
  /**
   * Get products
   * @Route("/products")
   * @Method("GET")
   */
  public function getAllAction() {

    $serialize = $this->get('jms_serializer');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine();

    $products = $em->getRepository('Couture\FrontBundle\Entity\Produit')->findAll();

    if (!$products) {

        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('error' => 'Resources not found for products')));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setStatusCode('400');
        return $response;
    }

    $response = new Response($serialize->serialize($products, 'json'));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
  }
}
```

**this is my class test:**

```
class ProductControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

  public function testGetAll() {

    $client = static::createClient();

    $client->request('GET', $client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('couture_front_product_getall'));

    $this->assertEquals(
            200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you comment that line, `!$products` is `false` and then your controller return a Reponse object with `application/json` content-type header. This response is considered as successful because its status code is 200 OK.

What I have seen in such scenario, is the use of data fixtures to test entities managed by doctrine entityManager.

Your test class may look like this ( not tested code, just to give you the idea behind):

```
class ProductControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

public function testGetAll() {

        $client = static::createClient();

        $fixtures = array('Acme\YourBundle\dataFixtures\LoadProductData');

        $this->loadFixtures($fixtures);

        $uri= $this->getUrl('couture_front_product_getall');

        $crawler= $client->request('GET',$uri);


        $this->assertEquals(200,$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() );

}
}
```